# Regex pattern to replace invalid comma before bracket

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to create a pattern to replace invalid commas (i.e comma before bracket end) in the below string

```
[{"terms": {"color": [ "Green", "White",]}},]
```

The invalid commas are : comma after `",]` and `},]`

So I need to write a pattern to find the last `",]` and `},]`

The pattern that I have now is

```
[\}]+\s*,+\s*\]
```

This looks to select `}},]` however I want only `},]`. 
It is selecting last two braces instead of just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actually offending substring is a comma followed by characters with structural semantics / syntax patterns as opposed to content. The preceding symbol (double  quote, brace) does not matter. So you can unify the patterns you are after and streamline your regex:

```
/,\s*([\]\}])/g
```

Replace any matches with capture group #1.

Add symbols to the character class inside the capture group as needed (I already added the closing brace).

Comment: Does this /,\s*([\]\}])/g pattern take care of empty spaces, line breaks, tabs, \r, \n, \t, etc between comma and bracket i.e like , and ]

Comment: the whitespace character class matches space, tab, carriage return, newline, form feed and vertical tab: `[ \t\r\n\f\v]`.